# Error: Cannot find module 'vue/compiler-sfc' Require stack: \node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js with vue version 2

Tags: laravel

I downloaded laravel 8 and it was ok but after typing php artisan ui vue --auth it got this error

Comment: In your pacakge.json what version of vue is in use?  eg "vue": "^2.5.17",

Comment: yes its vue": "^2.5.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your vuejs version to vuejs 3